# What exchange rate service to use for income section on visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, exchange, standard-visitor-visas

I would like to complete the income and expenditure section on my visa application in GBP.

What exchange rate should I use when converting from Nigerian Naira? I hear [Oanda](https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/) is correct but I am unsure.

Further, how do I indicate on the application the rate that I used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any exchange rate service, but they like it if you use [oanda.com](https://www.oanda.com/) because they get trained on that one for T1 and T2 applications.

Since Sterling is taking a caning right now, you would do a little better by picking today's closing rate, 70p to the dollar and use it for all your evidence going back 3 to 6 months. For Naira that would be 35p per 100 Naira  They are not going to make a big deal about it as long as you don't go cherry picking through historical rates. The rate is not as important for visitor applications as it is for PBS and settlement applications.

For representation, you can use the remarks section and add a statement like...

> A Sterling conversion rate of xxxx has been used. This was the closing
>   rate on xx/xx/xx per the internet Oanda service.

Comment: Do I need to include an oanda printout  for the said date as proof as its done  for T2 visas or its unnecessary.

Comment: No. Overkill. They will know if your rate is in the right ballpark.

Comment: OK...One more question.I used visa4uk website for the application but a friend says I should have used the one on gov.UK for the application..which one is the right one.this is my first time.

Comment: the visa4uk is the right form

Comment: @gayot...How do I explain why I'm staying in an hotel when im visiting family in UK since they stay outside London and I am staying in an hotel in London for my vacation.

Comment: No. This is not a discussion forum where comment threads can drift. You asked your question and you got your answer. You can upvote, downvote, accept, ignore or take your questions to a forum site. If you have new questions, use the 'ask a question' button to compose them. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and pose new questions as appropriate.

Comment: @AdeK the hotel/London/family visit question is reasonable. Just ask it as a new question.  You'll get more reputation points that way!  (...in case you care; more to the point, the site's design is supposed to keep it more focused so people can find what they need more easily.)

Comment: What is PBS _"PBS and settlement applications"_?

Comment: Expat applications, off-topic for us. http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions